# Bluescreen while reinstalling Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have an Acer Aspire V15 nitro black edition.

I recently ran into trouble while using it (repeated BSOD) so I decided to factory reset my computer. I copied the files I wanted and then started the factory reset. It was 64% done when it blue screened and now it's stuck booting, displaying for a split second the progress then starting again the boot etc...

What should I do?

Comment: That may be a hardware issue. Run a RAM test.

Comment: What details are shown on BSOD?

Comment: Error stop code : 0x000001d3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the computer was sent for repair.  There is no longer a problem to solve here and the problem can't be replicated or definitively answered.

Answer (score 0):

Computer sent to amazon to see if they can repair it :)